# set value within groups pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign a name to each grouping within pandas.

I have a dataframe, and a list of names:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'ids':[234, 345, 456, 444, 333, 22, 11, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]})


names = ['Matt', 'Jeff', 'Steph', 'Shannon']
```

I want to assign these names to each record, round-robin style. So I created a helper function to elongate this list to match the length.

```
def match_length(list_, length):
    return length//len(list_)*list_+list_[:length%len(list_)]

df['owner'] = match_length(names, len(df))

    a  ids    owner
    1  234     Matt
    1  345     Jeff
    2  456    Steph
    2  444  Shannon
    3  333     Matt
    4   22     Jeff
    5   11    Steph
    6    5  Shannon
    7    1     Matt
    7    2     Jeff
    8    3    Steph
    9    4  Shannon
   10    6     Matt
```

The problem I'm running into is that I want to make sure that the same person is assigned to each of the `'a'` groups. I don't want both 'Matt' and "Jeff' to own the first two records, only Matt should own them. I've tried `.groupby()` along with `.transform()`, `.apply()`, and `.assign()` with no luck. I'm not sure how to manipulate my list first. It *should* return..

```
    a  ids    owner
    1  234     Matt
    1  345     Matt
    2  456     Jeff
    2  444     Jeff
    3  333    Steph
    4   22  Shannon
    5   11     Matt
    6    5     Jeff
    7    1    Steph
    7    2    Steph
    8    3  Shannon
    9    4     Matt
   10    6     Jeff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you need ?

```
(df.groupby('a').ngroup()%4).map(dict(enumerate(names)))
Out[339]: 
0        Matt
1        Matt
2        Jeff
3        Jeff
4       Steph
5     Shannon
6        Matt
7        Jeff
8       Steph
9       Steph
10    Shannon
11       Matt
12       Jeff
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run loop through all the grouped elements.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10],
                   'ids':[234, 345, 456, 444, 333, 22, 11, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]})

grouped_df = df.groupby('a')
x = pd.DataFrame()
r = pd.DataFrame()

names = ['Matt', 'Jeff', 'Steph', 'Shannon']

for key, item in grouped_df:
    x = grouped_df.get_group(key).copy()
    x['owner'] = names[(key - 1) % len(names)]
    r = r.append(x)

print(r)
```

Output:

```
     a  ids    owner
    1  234     Matt
    1  345     Matt
    2  456     Jeff
    2  444     Jeff
    3  333    Steph
    4   22  Shannon
    5   11     Matt
    6    5     Jeff
    7    1    Steph
    7    2    Steph
    8    3  Shannon
    9    4     Matt
   10    6     Jeff
```

Answer (score 0):

if i have understood your problem:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10],
               'ids':[234, 345, 456, 444, 333, 22, 11, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6]})

def match_length(list_, length):
    return length//len(list_)*list_+list_[:length%len(list_)]

names = ['Matt', 'Jeff', 'Steph', 'Shannon']

dg = df.groupby('a')['ids'].apply(tuple).reset_index()
dg['owner'] = match_length(names, len(dg))

rows = []
_ = dg.apply(lambda row: [rows.append([row['a'], nn, row['owner']]) 
                         for nn in row.ids], axis=1)
dg = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=dg.columns)

print(dg)
```

so result:

```
     a  ids    owner
0    1  234     Matt
1    1  345     Matt
2    2  456     Jeff
3    2  444     Jeff
4    3  333    Steph
5    4   22  Shannon
6    5   11     Matt
7    6    5     Jeff
8    7    1    Steph
9    7    2    Steph
10   8    3  Shannon
11   9    4     Matt
12  10    6     Jeff
```